# Clarification on the Greek pronoun allos

Tags: greek

Calling all Greek experts! I'm particularly curious about the pronoun allos. I'm not educated enough in the nuances of Greek grammar to be able to accurately come up with an answer so I'd like to get some other opinions before I begin basing claims off of findings that hinge on this word.

After doing some searching, allos is translated as "another" in 56 verses. Only a handful of these verses include the word "to" before "another" and in all the cases, there is NO corresponding Greek word. I am assuming that the translators added the "to"s in order to make the usages of the pronoun make sense in English but if this is the case, it leaves these "to"s devoid of spiritual authority.

As minor as this seems, it leads to some large misconceptions if understood incorrectly. For instance, if we read "to another" and we think the pronoun it refers to is a person, then we are assuming that the person referred to by "to another" is DISTINCTLY SEPARATE from the subject. However, if we think that it is "another" person, then we can also include the subject with that person.

My main question is: how and in what circumstances would a usage of "allos" necessitate an addition of the word "to" according to Greek, grammatically.

Comment: I remember being taught it's full meaning could be understood as "one to another" But that may have been in a more specific use. It's been some time, I'll need to do some research. I'll find some example verse, but if you have any in mind where the meaning would be changed can you please include the reference?

Comment: It could be made on topic if specific passages where allos appears and it's meaning would change how we understand the passage. But, agreed, not as a pure Greek question. Was wrong in what I said before, though, the form of the particular use could change it to "to" or "of" or "for" and so on.

Comment: Kairos, welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! I think this question could be made on topic by giving us a specific example that you're confused about, but for now [it isn't](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/721/3555). (Also note that *allos* is technically not a pronoun; it's an adjective that is frequently used substantively. You may want to read up on [the dative case](http://www.ntgreek.org/learn_nt_greek/classify-dative.htm) as well.)

Comment: We put this on hold, but you should be able to [edit it](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/posts/13925/edit). If after editing it arises from a particular text per the [guidelines in our help center](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), we should be able to re-open it for you.